# Update list in real time

Tags: python

I am writing a code for elevator in which I have provided the initial conditions, now I want that new input for the elevator comes from another program and update the destination floor in real time.

Like in program elevator I have `elevator_list` and I want it to update using program input which store the date taken for user in `list_b`.

program input

```py
list_b=[]
while true:
    a = int(input("enter desired floor")
    list_b.append(a)
```

Now a want that date of `list_b` is sent to `elevator_list`.

Comment: So basically you want the contents of `list_b` be transfered to the elevator list in realtime?

Comment: Would you please share more of the code or upload the repo somewhere so I can read properly? cuz being honestly I did not understand what you're trying to

Comment: yes i want to transfer contents of list_b to elevator list in realtime, but both list are in different program.

Comment: @aero consider using a database, https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: repo link https://github.com/aero9560/elevator. in this program runs for initial inputs , i want that the program can accept extra inputs without stopping